# javascript regex replace all doublequotes in string unless the doublequote is followed by space or comma space

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I have an issue where someone isn't properly escaping double quotes in values later to be interpreted as a JSON string.

String example:

```
{"description":"This is my 12" pizza I ordered.","value":"1"}
```

When I try to have JSON.parse() handle this it gives an error because of the unescaped double quote (refering to the size in inches)

At first,  I thought - just do:

```
string.replace(/\"/g,'\"');
```

but of course this escapes all the valid double-quotes too.  So, I'm not an expert on regex, but I looked around for some answers and I think this requires a negative-lookahead?

Can someone help construct a regex for finding (for replacement) any sequence of doublequote where the next 2-character sequence following the offending doubleqoute is NOT space-comma?

I know this isn't a total universal fix, (getting the person to fix on their end would be), but unfortunately I don't have the luxury of a universal fix.

TIA

Update - instead of considering the example string (used for illustration only).  Is it possible to test for the presence of valid JSON before and after each doublequote - ie to look for any of the following characters 
        ,{[:

before and after each doublequote?  I guess this is what I was asking - can this be done with lookahead / behind regex?

Comment: This would be better done at creation time; how are you creating your _JSON_?

Comment: when you turn your "thing" into a json object using JSON.stringify, it should do the auto-escaping for you. You shouldn't need to do this yourself; can you show how you're building the object that you're turning into JSON in the first place?

Comment: The regex you're asking for won't solve your problem, because the double quotes in front of the words 'description', 'this', and 'value' shouldn't be escaped, but aren't immediately followed by comma or space characters.

Comment: How would you handle this case? `{"description":"I'd like a 10", or maybe a 12", and make it "thin crust""}` Gonna be pretty hard to get this right. Getting the JSON corrected isn't just a "universal" fix, it's the *only* fix. Why are they generating this by hand instead of using a proper JSON stringifier? What language is the server code in? Every popular server language has a JSON generator available.

Comment: To answer the questions of the origin of the malformed JSON string - I'm not creating the string, so I can't fix it on my end. I understand that getting the JSON right is the only real fix, but if that isn't possible I'm looking for as robust an alternative as possible.  Believe me - I'm not happy with having to deal with bad JSON as the only solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I can do, taking advantage of the fact that in JSON an unescaped quote can only occur in certain places.

```
input = '{"description":"This is my 12" pizza, and I want "thin crust"","value":"1"}';
console.log(input);
output = input.replace(/{"/g, '_OPEN_').replace(/":"/g, '_COLON_').replace(/","/g, '_COMMA_').replace(/"}/g, '_CLOSE_');
output = output.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
output = output.replace(/_OPEN_/g, '{"').replace(/_COLON_/g, '":"').replace(/_COMMA_/g, '","').replace(/_CLOSE_/g, '"}');
console.log(output)
```

Produces

```
{"description":"This is my 12" pizza, and I want "thin crust"","value":"1"}
{"description":"This is my 12\" pizza, and I want \"thin crust\"","value":"1"}
```

You can replace 'OPEN', 'CLOSE' etc with strings less likely to occur in the input, perhaps even control characters if you don't mind the regexes being cryptic. But as others have noted, there is no solution that will work in all cases. No matter what you do, there is a value that could occur in the description text that will mess you up, because unlike properly generated JSON, the syntax you're trying to parse is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

A way: rebuild the json string:

```
var str = '{"description":"This is my 12" pizza I ordered.","value":"1"}';
var regex = /"(.*?)"(?=\s*([,:])\s*"|(}))/g;
var result = '{';

var arr = regex.exec(str);

while (arr != null) {
    result += '"' + arr[1].replace(/\\?"/g, '\\"') + '"';
    if (arr[2]) result += arr[2];
    if (arr[3]) result += arr[3];
    arr = regex.exec(str);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is good if your certain of the description content because a value of:  {"description":"This, "pizza","is my 12" pizza", I ordered.","value":"1"}  does not work with this solution whereas it does in mine above.

Answer (score 0):

Not a one liner regex, but I think it is safer to do it this way:

```
 json_string = '{"description":"This is my 12" pizza: which can also contain other "," which would break in a one liner regex.","value":"1"}';
 console.log(json_string);

 // save the value for later use
 var value = json_string.match(/"value":"(.+)"}$/)[1];

 // isolate just the description value..

 // remove the ","value... from the end
 var desc = json_string.replace(/","value":".+"}$/, '');

 // remove the opening {"description":" from the description value
 desc = desc.replace(/^{"description":"/, '');

 // any remaining " in the description are unwanted to replace them
 desc = desc.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
 console.log(desc);

 // now put it all back together - if you wanted too - but really you already have the description and value parsed out of the string
 json_string = '{"description":"'+desc+'","value":"'+value+'"}'

 console.log(json_string);
```

The console output looks like:

```
{"description":"This is my 12" pizza: which can also contain other "," which would break in a one liner regex.","value":"1"}

This is my 12&quot; pizza: which can also contain other &quot;,&quot; which would break in a one liner regex.

{"description":"This is my 12&quot; pizza: which can also contain other &quot;,&quot; which would break in a one liner regex.","value":"1"}
```

**NOTE**  This method won't break if say the description also contained any of the patterns that you might use in as part of a regex one liner

Answer (score 0):

Try this replacement:

```
repl = str.replace(/"(?= )/g, "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering my own question and as so many of you pointed out, correctly, fixing bad JSON after the fact is impossible in a complete manner due to the ambiguity injected by a stray, un-escaped double-quote character.  Probably this should be a correct answer, unfortunately it wouldn't solve my problem.

For those who hit this same problem - I hope the function below helps band-aid until you can get the source of the erroneous JSON fixed.  Essentially you must look at each double quote, then peer ahead AND behind two characters (at least) and evaluate based on the previous / next characters whether its likely a valid use of doubleqoute in JSON or invalid.  If its invalid you splice in an escape character.  the function below does this pretty well, though depending on the extent of malformity of JSON due to the double-quote you may need to extend this function a bit.  My hope is that for those in my situation this at least provides a good starting point.

Thanks to all that contributed - the sheer number and breadth of potential solutions was pretty awesome to review!

```
// fix unescaped double quotes / malformed JSON
function cleanseJSON(jsonStr)
{
  for(var k=0;k<jsonStr.length;k++)
  { 
    if(jsonStr.charAt(k)=='"')
    {
      var prevChar=jsonStr.charAt(k-1);
      var prevChar2=jsonStr.charAt(k-2);
      var nextChar=jsonStr.charAt(k+1);
      var nextChar2=jsonStr.charAt(k+2);
      var esc="\\";
      var isValid=false;
      var prevFix=false;
      var postFix=false;

      switch(prevChar)
      {
        case ':':
        case '{':
        case ',':
        case '[':
        case '\\':   // already escaped
          isValid=true;
          break;
        default:
          prevFix=true;
      }

      switch(nextChar)
      {
        case ':':
        case '}':
        case ',':
          if(nextChar2==' '){   // if there is a comma, but the next is a space consider it invalid JSON
            break;  
          }
        case ']':
        case '\\':   // already escaped
          isValid=true;
          break;
        default:
          postFix=true;
      }
      // first test to ensure the quote is likely bogus
      if(!isValid)
      {
        if(prevFix){
          jsonStr = [jsonStr.slice(0, k), esc, jsonStr.slice(k)].join('');   
        } else {
          if(postFix){
            jsonStr = [jsonStr.slice(0, k+1), esc, jsonStr.slice(k+1)].join('');
          }
        }
      } // if not valid "
    } // if we find a doublequote
  } // for each char in the jsonStr
  return jsonStr;
}
```