# Search and replace double quotes inside existing double quotes in JSON

Tags: regex, json, double, quotes

I have data that loks like this:

"contributors": null,
"truncated": false,
"text": "This is "what" we call text",
"coordinates": null

Notice the double quotes inside existing double quotes for the "text" node (bad data, I know). The data set is HUGE, so manual clean-up would be out of the question. I'm streaming the data using Node.js, so I can do the replace on a line-by-line basis. Is there any way with JS to escape (or change to single quote) these instances? Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not with Node.js, since you need a lookbehind assertion to negate valid JSON schema characters (`:` and `,`).

You could do this though, in something like Python. It won't catch everything though, and you'll probably have to do some manual cleanup:

```
(?<![:,] )"(?![:,])
```

Expand on it if you want here: https://regex101.com/r/rB4vV9/1

Related: why is your datasource not spitting out valid JSON, and why haven't you gone knocking on the owner's door do tell them they're doing it wrong?

Comment: The 'door knocking' will be coming, rest assured. Right now, I just have to solve this issue asap.

Comment: Well, there's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221173/javascript-regex-replace-all-doublequotes-in-string-unless-the-doublequote-is-fo